# Handlebars template not getting the proper result in the double step drop down menu

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars.js template to make main and subnavi links, i am getting main step of the links, but the sublink not getting, still i am getting double step links properly on first links without proper text and link info.

my template :

```
<script id="navi-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each links}}
                {{#if subLinks}}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{link}}">{{label}}</a>
                        <ul>
                            {{#each subLinks}}
                                <a href="{{link}}">{{label}}</a>
                            {{/each}}
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                {{else}}
                    <li><a href="{{link}}">{{label}}</a></li>
                {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

I updated my data and jquery what i am using in jsfiffle: [click to visit fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmru3/)

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure the `{{#each}}` construction requires you to use `{{this}}`

```
                       {{#each subLinks}}
                            <a href="{{link}}">{{this}}</a>
                        {{/each}}
```

Think of it as how `i`(or any other counter) is used in `for` cycles.
If you iterate over objects you can do stuff like

```
                   {{#each object}}
                       {{this.name}} : {{this.content}}
                    {{/each}}
```

While your object is

```
var Example = {
name: "Object",
content: "example"
}
```

Comment: yes, very thanks to you. got the point. issue fixed. (By parallel i got issue in object as well)